# Nodejs absolute paths in windows with forward slash

Tags: node.js, windows, webpack, absolute-path

Can I have absolute paths with forward slashes in windows in nodejs? I am using something like this :

```
global.__base = __dirname + '/';
var Article = require(__base + 'app/models/article');
```

But on windows the build is failing as it is requiring something like `C:\Something\Something/apps/models/article`. I aam using webpack. So how to circumvent this issue so that the requiring remains the same i.e. `__base + 'app/models/src'`?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/path.html

Comment: @Amadan as I said I doont want to change how I require the module

Comment: If you don't want to change your code, what do you expect us to do?

Comment: I was talking about alernative way around `global.__base = __dirname + '/';`. I am willing to change that as that happens only once in the code

Comment: You are still fixing `/` as the separator in `app/models/article`. I don't know whether or not `C:\Something\Something/apps/models/article` works on Windows (I never develop for it), but `path.join(__dirname, 'app', 'models', 'article')` does.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I know it is a bit late to answer but I think my answer will help some visitors.

In `Node.js` you can easily get your current running file name and its directory by just using `__filename` and `__dirname` variables respectively.

In order to correct the forward and back slash accordingly to your system you can use `path` module of `Node.js`

```
var path = require('path');
```

Like here is a messed path and I want it to be correct if I want to use it on my server. Here the `path` module do everything for you

> var randomPath = "desktop//my folder/\myfile.txt";

```
var correctedPath = path.normalize(randomPath); //that's that

console.log(correctedPath);
```

> ```
> desktop/my folder/myfile.txt
> ```

If you want the absolute path of a file then you can also use `resolve` function of `path` module

```
var somePath = "./img.jpg";
var resolvedPath = path.resolve(somePath);

console.log(resolvedPath);
```

> ```
> /Users/vikasbansal/Desktop/temp/img.jpg
> ```

Comment: @VikasBansat: `path.normalize(path.resolve('./'))` - is effectively the way you suggest. However this does not resolve the issue under Windows 8 (at least).

Comment: This doesn't work, at all. Backslashes remain backslashes.

Comment: This only works for UNIX systems. For Windows, default path delimiter is backslash

Comment: After testing, this doesn't work on windows. Slashes still remain backward with this. This answer should not be the accepted one, because it doesn't solve the problem for Windows, for which it was asked for.

Answer (score 31):

it's 2020, 5 years from the question was published, but I hope that for somebody my answer will be useful. I've used the replace method, here is my code(express js project):

```
const viewPath = (path.join(__dirname, '../views/')).replace(/\\/g, '/')

exports.articlesList = function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(viewPath + 'articlesList.html');
}
```

Comment: works nicely for me to insert the forward slashed path into a database

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer doesn't actually answer the question most people come here for.
If you're looking to normalize all path separators (possibly for string work), here's what you need.

All the code segments have the node.js built-in module `path` imported to the `path` variable.
They also have the variable they work from stored in the immutable variable `str`, unless otherwise specified.

If you have a string, here's a quick one-liner normalize the string to a forward slash (/):

```js
const answer = path.resolve(str).split(path.sep).join("/");
```

You can normalize to any other separator by replacing the forward slash (/).

If you want just an array of the parts of the path, use this:

```js
const answer = path.resolve(str).split(path.sep);
```

Once you're done with your string work, use this to create a path able to be used:

```js
const answer = path.resolve(str);
```

From an array, use this:

```js
// assume the array is stored in constant variable arr
const answer = path.join(...arr);
```

Answer (score 3):

I finally did it like this:

```
var slash = require('slash');
var dirname = __dirname;
if (process.platform === 'win32') dirname = slash(dirname);

global.__base = dirname + '/';
```

And then to require `var Article = require(__base + 'app/models/article');`. This uses the npm package slash (which replaces backslashes by slashes in paths and handles some more cases)

Comment: I'd rather recommend using https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_sep which is the very purpose of this feature ;) And make it a one-liner!

Comment: @Vadorequest Thanks for this! Never heard about `path.sep` before - it was just what is was looking for!

Comment: Thanks for reminding me this solution exists, I had completely forgotten about it ^^'

Answer (score 1):

This is the approach I use, to save some processing:

```
const path = require('path');

// normalize based on the OS
const normalizePath = (value: string): string {
  return path.sep === '\' 
    ? value.replace(/\\/g, '/')
    : value;
}

console.log('abc/def'); // leaves as is
console.log('abc\def'); // on windows converts to `abc/def`, otherwise leave as is
```

Answer (score 1):

It is already too late but the actual answer is using **`path.sep` or `path.join` depends on the requirement.**

In Windows directory path will be "" and Linux "/" so the path library will do this work automatically.

```
const path = require("path");
const abPath = path.join(__base ,'app','models','article')
```

OR

```
const path = require("path");
const abPath = __base + 'app'+ path.sep +'models'+ path.sep +'article';
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend against this, as it is patching node itself, but... well, no changes in how you require things.

```
(function() {
  "use strict";
  var path = require('path');
  var oldRequire = require;
  require = function(module) {
    var fixedModule = path.join.apply(path, module.split(/\/|\\/));
    oldRequire(fixedModule);
  }
})();
```

Answer (score -1):

Use path module

```
const path = require("path");
var str = "test\test1 (1).txt";
console.log(str.split(path.sep)) // This is only on Windows
```

Answer (score -1):

Windows uses `\`, Linux and mac use `/` for path prefixes

For Windows   : `'C:\\Results\\user1\\file_23_15_30.xlsx'`

For Mac/Linux: `/Users/user1/file_23_15_30.xlsx`

If the file has `\` - it is windows, use fileSeparator as `\`, else use `/`

```
let path=__dirname; // or filePath
fileSeparator=path.includes('\')?"\":"/"  
newFilePath = __dirname + fileSeparator + "fileName.csv";
```