# Nuxt.config.js is not in cwd

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I want to use 'npm run generate' in Nuxt project, but i have error:

```
Path C:/Users/Марина/OneDrive/Desktop/weHost/zabota-dialog/nuxt.config.js is not in cwd C:\Users\Марина\OneDrive\Desktop\weHost\zabota-dialog
```

Nuxt.config.js now in Project root directory. File contents:

```js
export default {
  // Target: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-target
  target: "static",

  // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
  head: {
    title: "dialog-zabota",
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: "en"
    },
    meta: [
      { charset: "utf-8" },
      { name: "viewport", content: "width=device-width, initial-scale=1" },
      { hid: "description", name: "description", content: "" }
    ],
    link: [{ rel: "icon", type: "image/x-icon", href: "/favicon.ico" }]
  },

  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  css: ["./assets/less/main.less"],
  styleResources: {
    less: ["./assets/less/static/variables.less", "./assets/less/static/font-face.less"]
  },
  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: [],

  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  components: true,

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  buildModules: ["@nuxtjs/style-resources"],

  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [],

  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
  build: {}
};
```

What i do wrong? Why it's not run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how to fix it since I'm on an UNIX-based system but there is actually a difference

```
C:\Users\Марина\OneDrive\Desktop\weHost\zabota-dialog
```

vs

```
C:/Users/Марина/OneDrive/Desktop/weHost/zabota-dialog/nuxt.config.js
```

The slashes do not match, `\` vs `/`. Did you do some specific configuration with your system?

---

This one may help: [Nodejs absolute paths in windows with forward slash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34329149/8816585)

Or any google query with `npm backslash windows` keywords.

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend don't use cyrillic later in path
.Its help for me

Answer (score 0):

I think its could happen because of non ASCII characters too. I'm using Windows in Turkish so there was a "/Masaüstü/" part on my path, I carried my folder to C:/src and problem fixed.