# front slash changes to back slash after #

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, electron

Hello I am doing this electron project and I came across this issue where when I give this path

```
`file://${path.join(__dirname, `../build/index.html#/view/${arg}`)}`
```

I was hoping for this,

```
file:///C:/Users/admin/AppData/Local/Programs/electrondesktop/resources/app.asar/build/index.html#/view/61995a6fcf31f7cddedcce59
```

Instead, I get,

```
file:///C:/Users/admin/AppData/Local/Programs/electrondesktop/resources/app.asar/build/index.html#\view\61995a6fcf31f7cddedcce59
```

Notice how the forward-slash("/") changes to back-slash("\") after the hash(#) symbol

**index.html#/view/61995a6fcf31f7cddedcce59**

**index.html#\view\61995a6fcf31f7cddedcce59**

How do I fix this?

I'm using electron with react btw.

Comment: arg is only a variable containing  this value ‘ 61995a6fcf31f7cddedcce59’ would it still work? @pilchard

Comment: hmmm, not sure then. not able to reproduce this behavior on MacOS, Windows specific?

Comment: Windows @pilchard

Comment: possible discussion here: [Nodejs absolute paths in windows with forward slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34329149/nodejs-absolute-paths-in-windows-with-forward-slash)

Comment: tried that, didnt help much at all. There has to be some sort of solution for this. @pilchard

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the Answer!

Apparently, there is another way to avoid slashes after #

Its something like this,

```
url.format({
         pathname: path.join(__dirname,`index.html`),
         protocol:'file',
         slashes:true,
         hash:`#/view/61995a6fcf31f7cddedcce59`
       })
```

__dirname gives the path I needed. i.e. `file:///C:/Users/admin/AppData/Local/Programs/electrondesktop/resources/app.asar/build/`